# Laravel Session data is not instantly accessible

Tags: php, laravel, session, single-page-application, inertiajs

I have been trying to save the form data to session if a user reloads the page they are working on.

My current setup involves an ajax call from a 'beforeunload' event listener

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', leaving());

function leaving() { 
   axios.post('save-to-session', this.obj)
},
```

This does successfully send the data over to the controller upon refresh which then saves it to session

```
public function saveToSession()
{
    session()->put('data', request()->all());
    return response()->json();
}
```

However, if I refresh the page again and dd() the session my session shows like it was not updated. On a second refresh to the same page session updates without initiating the 'saveToSession' method.

```
public function index()
{
    dd(session()->all());
}
```

Can anyone figure out the source of this behaviour or what would be a traditional way to save data into session with instant access?

- For more info I am using Intertia and Vue.
- My session settings in env looks like below
- My session file does get updated

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

Comment: I cant tell whats happening, you say the  `/save-to-session` is not called the second time. Also `beforeunload` is not completely reliable as you might expect: a crashing browser will not call that endpoint. So long story short: if the `'data'` key is there at one point, and later it is not, it is overwritten. You can try some static tests and see if the session variable persists (which it should).

Comment: the flow is refreshing the page calls /save-to-session then immediately after, when I dd() the session->all(), the 'data' key is not updated however if dd() session->all() a second time then the 'data' key is updated.
It is quite strange since I now found out that I can pull the session data with axios after the vue mounts and would receive updated version of session. Does not feel right but it will have to do for now until I figure out what is happening

Comment: You can try `session()->save()`, since by default the session is persisted at the end of the request lifecycle (if i recall correctly). Im not sure if that fixes your issue because I dont recognize the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: I did come accross save() while frantically googling too it has somehow helped yet thanks! However the issue still exists I think mainly due to the fact that when I refresh, first index() gets called which has the old version of session then saveToSession gets called which is why I keep seeing the old session on the front end hence why I can find the updated version of session if I send another axios to fetch session data on my vue component's mounted hook it works